# Is there any way of extending the Point (or any other) type with overloaded operators?

Tags: .net, vb.net, operator-overloading, extension-methods

In a loop within an `OnPaint` event, I draw a string using `DrawString`. Before drawing the string, the client rectangle `oRect` needs to be offset by some pixels. Being in a loop, it is clear that this offsetting must be undone, or they will add up.

This works as intended:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    ...

    oRect.Offset(oOffset)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(sText, oFont, oBrush, oRect, oStringFormat)
    oRect.Offset(New Point(- oOffset.X, - oOffset.Y))

    ...
End Sub
```

However, it would be much nicer to undo the offset by simply specifying a negation operator. Of course I could go on with an extension named `Negate` and apply it as follows:

```
    oRect.Offset(Negate(oOffset))
```

However, I'd like to do this:

```
    oRect.Offset(- oOffset)
```

Trying to specify an extension in a module for an overloaded operator tells me, that I can't apply extensions to operators.

Is there any other way of extending the Point (or any other) type with overloaded operators?

Comment: Have you tried the [other offset method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tazxys86(v=vs.110).aspx)?  oRect.Offset(-oOffset.x, -oOffset.y)  Also, can you just offset it once on creation? That would remove the whole logic here.

Comment: @the_lotus, oOffset is a property of an object managing text. There are multiple such texts, being processed in a loop, in which above code executes. Each text may have a different offset. Thanks for showing the other overload, I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: An other option could be to create a new rect instead of a new point. The new rect would have the offset, that way you'll do the operation only once instead of twice.